# ld: library not found for (on Simulator only)

Tags: xcode, ios7, clang

Suddenly began getting this error when running my app on iOS 7 Simulator.

> ld: library not found for -lacmobileshim
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

On Device this problem doesn't happen and the app runs OK.

Have already searched for this library inside SDK but couldn't find it. Have no idea what's going on cause it was running OK both on Simulator and Devices before and haven't added any additional library to my project.

Is there a way to set Library Search Path in Build Settings just for this library?

Should reinstall SDK be a workaround?

These are the libraries i'm including in my project:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After get the same headache as updated to Xcode 6/iOS 8 sdk, just found a simple way to solve this issue with libacmobileshim.dylib and also other dynamic libraries that were causing the same problem when building the app on simulator. Just delete the dynamic libraries from Build Phases settings and the app is running perfectly again on simulator. Hope it may help someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

libacmobileshim.dylib is in the iOS Device SDK, but it is not in the simulator SDK.  External developers should have no need for this library, so I'm confused as to why you're linking against it.

Looking at that list of libraries that you're linking against, I suspect a bunch of them aren't even needed by your project.  You should audit that list and eliminate unnecessary linkage.

Comment: yes you're completely right @jeremy-huddleston-sequoia, that's what I did thanks!